# Unable to Rerender primefaces 5 Charts after Actionlistenter

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I have very basic web application that contains one page index.xhtml containing primefaces chart to be rendered through link/button/menuitem. Problem is Chart is not rendered at all but after refreshing the page.

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<f:view>
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form >
             <p:dock position="bottom">
                 <p:menuitem value="Home" icon="images/img1.png" url="#"/>
                <p:menuitem value="Chrome" icon="images/img1.png" url="#"/>
            </p:dock>


            <p:breadCrumb>
                <p:menuitem value="#{primeViewBean.applicationName}"/>

                <p:menuitem actionListener="#{primeViewAction.drawChart}" icon="pieImage" 
                            update="pieChart">
                    <f:param name="chartType" value="PieChart"/>
                </p:menuitem>

                <p:menuitem actionListener="#{primeViewAction.drawChart}" icon="barImage"
                            update="barChart">
                    <f:param name="chartType" value="BarChart"/>
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem actionListener="#{primeViewAction.drawChart}" icon="lineImage"
                            update="lineChart">
                    <f:param name="chartType" value="LineChart"/>
                </p:menuitem>

            </p:breadCrumb>

                <p:chart id="pieChart"  type="pie" model="#{primeViewBean.pieChartmodel}" />
                <p:chart id="barChart"  type="bar" model="#{primeViewBean.barChartmodel}"/>
                <p:chart id="lineChart"  type="line" model="#{primeViewBean.lineChartmodel}"/>

        </h:form>

    </h:body>
        </f:view>
</html>
```

My Action class have draw method as :

```
public void drawChart(ActionEvent e){
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

        String chartType = String.valueOf(request.getParameter("chartType"));
        ChartModel model = PrimeChartFactory.getChartInstance(chartType).getModel();
        if(primeBean!=null){
            if(model instanceof PieChartModel)
                primeBean.setPieChartmodel((PieChartModel)model);
            if(model instanceof BarChartModel)
                primeBean.setBarChartmodel((BarChartModel)model);
            if(model instanceof LineChartModel)
                primeBean.setLineChartmodel((LineChartModel)model);

            primeBean.setPageName("Usman Liaqat Set");
        }
    }
```

I have used @all/@form also but not working,
using Glassfish 4. on netbeans 
Primefaces 5
Firefox 33.0

Comment: Observe the traffic in on your network tab in your js console; do you see the request and a proper ajax response returning from the server onclick?

Comment: yes response is there but it does not render it.

Comment: need help guys... let me know if i am missing any part here ?

Comment: paste the ajax response here

Comment: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="j_idt4:pieChart"><![CDATA[<div id="j_idt4:pieChart"></div><script id="j_idt4:pieChart_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Chart','widget_j_idt4_pieChart',{id:'j_idt4:pieChart',type:'pie',data:[[["Brand 1",540],["Brand 2",325],["Brand 3",702],["Brand 4",421]]],title:'Simple Pie',legendPosition:'w'},'charts');});</script>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[3974479214440068551:-6453227592302142095]]></update></changes></partial-response>